Passing a Linked List to Function LeetCode Add2number
I was doing a leetcode problem and realized I've never passed a linked list to a function before. So, now I'm attempting to implement a linked list using a class that inherits the structure of a linked list. In my main code I'm attempting to pass a ListNode* type to the function add2numbers that is a replica of the leetcode problem along with the structure. From what I see in the watch window, Num_List *list; contains all the data of the linked list I just made but I can't pass that due to a type complaint because its from the Num_List class.
#include<iostream>
#include"List_Node.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {

    Num_List *list, *list2;



    cout << "List 1" << endl;
    cout << "--------" << endl;
    list->appendNode(1);
    list->appendNode(2);
    list->appendNode(3);
    list->displayList();
    cout << "List 2" << endl;
    cout << "--------" << endl;
    list2->appendNode(3);
    list2->appendNode(2);
    list2->appendNode(1);
    list2->displayList();
    
    list->addTwoNumbers((ListNode*)list->val, (ListNode*)list2->val);
    return 0;
}
 

#pragma once
#ifndef LIST_NODE_H
#define LIST_NODE_H

struct ListNode {
    int val;
    struct ListNode* next;
    ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
    ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
    ListNode(int x, ListNode* next) : val(x), next(next) {}

};
ListNode* head;
class Num_List: public ListNode {
private:

public:
    
    //constructor
    Num_List() {
        head = nullptr;
    }
    //Destructor
    ~Num_List();

    void appendNode(int);
    void insertNode(int);
    void deleteNode(int);
    void displayList()const;
    int addTwoNumbers(ListNode*, ListNode*);
};

#endif

#include"List_Node.h"
#include <iostream>

Num_List::~Num_List()
{
    ListNode* nodePtr;// pointer to traverse list
    ListNode* nextNode;//pointer to next node
    
    //Position nodePtr at the head of the list
    nodePtr = head;

    //while nodeptr is no at the end of the list..
    while (nodePtr != nullptr) {
        //save a pointer to the next node.
        nextNode = nodePtr->next;

        //delete the current node.
        delete nodePtr;

        //Position nodePtr a the next node for next loop
        nodePtr = nextNode;
    }
}

void Num_List::appendNode(int num)
{
    ListNode* newNode;
    ListNode* nodePtr;

    //Allocate a new node and store data there;
    newNode = new ListNode;
    newNode->val = num;
    newNode->next = nullptr;

    //If there are no nodes in list 
    //then make a newNode the head node.
    if (!head) {
        head = newNode;
    }
    else {
        //Initealize nodePtr to head of the list.
        nodePtr = head;

        //Find the last node in the list
        while (nodePtr->next)
            nodePtr = nodePtr->next;

        //Insert a newNode as the last node ie already points to nullPtr
        nodePtr->next = newNode;
    }
}

void Num_List::insertNode(int num)
{
    ListNode* newNode; // a new node
    ListNode* nodePtr;// a  pointer to nodes used to traverse list
    ListNode* previousNode = nullptr;// the previous node

    //Allocate a new node and sotre the num there.
    newNode = new ListNode;
    newNode->val = num;
    //if there are no nodes in the list make newNode the head node;
    if (!head)
    {
        head = newNode;
        newNode->next = nullptr;
    }
    else {//otherwise insert a newNode
        //Position nodePtr at the ahead of the list
        nodePtr = head;

        //Initialize previousNode to nullptr
        previousNode = nullptr;

        //skip all nodes whose value is less than input value
        while (nodePtr != nullptr && nodePtr->val < num) {
            previousNode = nodePtr;
            nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
        }

        //If the new node is to be the 1st in the list,
        //insert it before all other nodes.
        if (previousNode == nullptr)
        {
            head = newNode;
            newNode->next = nodePtr;

        }
        else {//otherwise insert after the previous node.
            previousNode->next = newNode;
            newNode->next = nodePtr;
        }

    }
}void Num_List::deleteNode(int num)
{
    ListNode* nodePtr;// a  pointer to nodes used to traverse list
    ListNode* previousNode = nullptr;// the previous node

    //determine if the first node contains the data
    if (!head)return;
    if (head->val == num) { 
        nodePtr = head->next;
        delete head;
        head = nodePtr;
    }
    else {
        //Initialize nodePtr to the head of list
        nodePtr = head;

        //skip all nodes whose value is not the input value
        while (nodePtr != nullptr && nodePtr->val != num) {
            previousNode = nodePtr;
            nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
        }

        //If nodePtr is not at the end of the list,
        //link the previous node to the node after nodePtr, 
        //then delete nodePtr
        if (nodePtr) {
            previousNode->next = nodePtr->next;
            delete nodePtr;
        }

    }
}
using namespace std;
void Num_List::displayList() const
{
    
    ListNode* nodePtr;//pointer to a node int ListNode class
    //position nodePtr at the head of the list.
    nodePtr = head;

    //while nodePtr points to a node, traverse the list
    while (nodePtr) {

        //display value contained in node
        cout << nodePtr->val << endl;
            //move to next node
        nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
    }
}

int Num_List::addTwoNumbers(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2) {
    ListNode* head = new ListNode(0);
    ListNode* tail = head;
    int carry = 0;
    while (l1 != nullptr || l2 != nullptr || carry != 0) {
        int dig1 = (l1 != nullptr) ? l1->val : 0;
        int dig2 = (l1 != nullptr) ? l1->val : 0;

        int sum = dig1 + dig2 + carry;
        int digit = sum % 10;
        carry = sum / 10;
        ListNode* newNode = new ListNode(digit);
        tail->next = newNode;
        tail = tail->next;
        l1 = (l1 != nullptr) ? l1->next : nullptr;
        l2 = (l2 != nullptr) ? l2->next : nullptr;
    }
    ListNode* result = head->next;
    delete head;
    return (int) result;
}

Above I tried to some wonky type conversion but no luck. I'd like it to accept the linked list but I'm pretty sure I didn't actually pass it the Linked list but just a reference that happens to hold the same data. Its like I'm passing a phantom list right now because I haven't actually set anything to represent the linked list like linked_list= list1;

ListNode not that much yet, Num_List is far worse! It shouldn't inherit from ListNode and the classes head is a global variable – resulting in all lists using the same head (or the other way round you only can meaningfully create one single list). Do not declare first and assign later, do it in a single line: Node* node = head; and declare variables at the smallest scope necessary (only where they are needed; e.g. nodePtr within append only inside the else branch).

Do not comment the obvious (e.g. all of us can immediately see that you are initialising nodePtr with head, no comment needed – counter example: if you had several different options to initialise a variable then you might want to comment why you chose that specific one).

Maybe a bit more advanced: It doesn't appear meaningful to create ListNodes on their own, without surrounding Num_List. It thus would be more reasonable to make the former a nested class of the latter.

Err..., I agree that Leetcode is a terrible place to learn a language. But it is not their target. And it is a correct way to practice algorithmics, whatever the language. You are all right when saying that in real world programs the standard libraries are always the way to go. But knowing the algorithms, their use cases and their limits is important for the conception phase.

@SergeBallesta I'd agree on that as well. But looking at the design presented above (most notably the global variable that actually should be a member) gives me the impression the question author indeed still is in the learning phase…

I actually had the struct inside the class originally and ended up moving it outside and adding that inheritance feat. to try make list equal  the data in Listnode* l1 which lead me to move outside so i can use it in the main. Yea I'm in the learning phase, made past c++ oop cis22c. Doing discrete math right now. I decided to try leetcode because I feel like most of what I learned is basic but not really applicable to a real job so I figured look at leetcode to encounter unfamiliar topics I haven't seen before. I have the book Starting Out with C++ from Control structures through objects 9 ed.

Glad to see someone make a proper linked list class for this. For a while, I thought I was the only one!
In production code, you should prefer to use std::list or std::forward_list for your linked lists. It is unfortunate that LeetCode does not do that in its problems. Given that LeetCode does not, writing a custom linked list class is the next best thing.
Using inheritance, however, is the wrong idea. Public inheritance often implies an "is-a" relationship, and that does not exist here. A List is not a special type of ListNode.
So, the design below does not use inheritance. In addition, it stores pointer head within the List class as a member variable. You can see the complete code for class LeetCode_ForwardList below, but the important thing for your question are these two functions:
class LeetCode_ForwardList
{
    ListNode* head{ nullptr };
public:
    // ...

    ListNode* get() const noexcept {
        return head;  // Retain ownership.
    }
    ListNode* release() noexcept {
        return std::exchange(head, nullptr);  // Relinquish ownership.
    }
}

Member functions get and release are modeled after std::unique_ptr. They both return the value of pointer head, but get retains ownership of the list (and the responsibility to delete the list nodes when the lifetime of the LeetCode_ForwardList object ends). Function release relinquishes ownership, and sets pointer head to nullptr.
Although the listing below omits source code for function addTwoNumbers, the solution I wrote uses function get. Thus, the caller in my program retains ownership of the lists. Depending how you code addTwoNumbers in your program, you can use either get or release.
Here is the driver that uses function get. Function solve is where addTwoNumbers is invoked.
// LeetCode_0002_Add_Two_Numbers.ixx
export module LeetCode_0002_Add_Two_Numbers;
import std;
import LeetCode_ForwardList;  // see below

//======================================================================
// to_int
//======================================================================
int to_int(LeetCode_ForwardList const& list) noexcept
{
    int i{}, place{ 1 };
    auto node{ list.get() };
    while (node) {
        i += place * node->value;
        place *= 10;
        node = node->next;
    }
    return i;
}
//======================================================================
// to_list
//======================================================================
LeetCode_ForwardList to_list(int i)
{
    // Precondition established by caller: i >= 0
    LeetCode_ForwardList list;
    list.push_front(i % 10);
    auto tail{ list.get() };
    for (i /= 10; i != 0; i /= 10) {
        tail->next = new ListNode(i % 10);
        tail = tail->next;
    }
    return list;
}
//======================================================================
// Solution
// This class is supplied by LeetCode, as part of its problem 
// specification.
//
// Depending how you code your solution, it may not be necessary to 
// declare a `LeetCode_ForwardList` object in function `addTwoNumbers`. 
// In case your solution does, however, you should use function `release` 
// to return the `ListNode*` required by function `addTwoNumbers`.
//
// For example:
// 
//   LeetCode_ForwardList sum;
//   ...
//   return sum.release();  // Pass ownership to the caller.
//
// In case your function does not use a `LeetCode_ForwardList` object, 
// you will have to implement some other mechanism to catch any 
// `std::bad_alloc` objects that are thrown by your function, and then 
// delete any list nodes that were allocated prior to the `bad_alloc`.
// Otherwise, your function may leak memory. 
//
// See functions `to_int` and `to_list` (above) to get an idea of how 
// to program with `LeetCode_ForwardList`. They don't leak.
//======================================================================
class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* addTwoNumbers(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2) {
        return {};  // Stub function returns `nullptr`
    }
};
//======================================================================
// solve
//======================================================================
void solve(
    std::string_view heading,
    std::vector<int> v1,
    std::vector<int> v2)
{
    Solution s;
    LeetCode_ForwardList l1{ v1 }, l2{ v2 }, sum{ s.addTwoNumbers(l1.get(), l2.get()) };
    std::cout
        << heading
        << '\n'
        << "\n  Input: l1 = " << l1
        << ", l2 = " << l2
        << "\n  Output: " << sum
        << "\n  Explanation: " << to_int(l1) << " + " << to_int(l2) 
        << " = " << to_int(sum) << '.'
        << "\n\n";
}
//======================================================================
// driver
//======================================================================
export bool LeetCode_0002_Add_Two_Numbers() {
    std::cout << "LeetCode 2. Add Two Numbers"
        "\nhttps://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/"
        "\n\n";
    solve("Example 1", { 2, 4, 3 }, { 5, 6, 4 });
    solve("Example 2", { 0 }, { 0 });
    solve("Example 3", { 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9 }, { 9, 9, 9, 9 });
    solve("Example 4: Malformed lists", { 10, 12 }, { 34 });
    solve("Example 5: Malformed lists", { 1234 }, { 0 });
    return true;
}
// end file: LeetCode_0002_Add_Two_Numbers.ixx

LeetCode_ForwardList and ListNode
Here is the code for the list classes. Note the constructor that accepts a vector argument. That's where the lists are constructed for the examples in function solve (above).
// LeetCode_ForwardList.ixx
export module LeetCode_ForwardList;
import std;

//======================================================================
// ListNode
// 
// This struct is specified by certain problems at LeetCode, including 
// these:
// 
//   - LeetCode 2. Add Two Numbers
//   - LeetCode 234. Palindrome Linked List
// 
// In a proper design for a "forward linked list," `ListNode` would be 
// coded as a nested struct, within the list class itself, rather than 
// as a stand-alone struct. LeetCode, however, does not allow that 
// option. Its solution specifications require a stand-alone struct.
// 
// Worse yet, LeetCode does not define a list class to manage the nodes 
// of a linked list. Instead, it passes naked `ListNode` pointers, and 
// treats them as lists. No effort is made to implement any of the 
// special functions required by the "Rule of Five."
//======================================================================

export struct ListNode {
    int value{};
    ListNode* next{ nullptr };
    ListNode(
        int const value = 0,
        ListNode* const next = nullptr)
        : value{ value }
        , next{ next }
    {}
};

//======================================================================
// LeetCode_ForwardList
// 
// This class implements a forward linked list where each node holds an 
// integer value. It is a light-weight class intended for use only in 
// certain LeetCode problems that use the `ListNode` struct defined 
// above. As such, it is not intended to be an industrial-strength 
// library class. 
// 
// That said, this class does implement the "Rule of Five" (or, rather, 
// the "Rule of Four (and a half)", which, effectively, is the same 
// thing).
//======================================================================

export class LeetCode_ForwardList
{
    ListNode* head{ nullptr };
public:
    LeetCode_ForwardList() = default;
    LeetCode_ForwardList(ListNode* const head) : head{ head } {}
    LeetCode_ForwardList(std::vector<int> const& vec)
        : head{ nullptr }
    {
        try { push_front(vec); }
        catch (std::bad_alloc const&) { clear(); throw; }
    }

    // "Rule of Four (and a half)"

    ~LeetCode_ForwardList() noexcept {
        clear();
    }
    LeetCode_ForwardList(LeetCode_ForwardList const& that)
        : head{ nullptr }
    {
        if (that.head) {
            push_front(that.head->value);  // Nothing leaks if this throws.
            auto tail{ this->head };
            auto node{ that.head->next };
            while (node) {
                try { tail->next = new ListNode(node->value); }
                catch (std::bad_alloc const&) { clear(); throw; }  // Prevent leaks.
                tail = tail->next;
                node = node->next;
            }
        }
    }
    LeetCode_ForwardList(LeetCode_ForwardList&& that) noexcept
        : head{ std::exchange(that.head, nullptr) }
    {}
    LeetCode_ForwardList& operator= (LeetCode_ForwardList that) noexcept {
        swap(that);
        return *this;
    }
    void swap(LeetCode_ForwardList& that) noexcept {
        using std::swap;
        swap(this->head, that.head);
    }
    friend void swap(LeetCode_ForwardList& a, LeetCode_ForwardList& b) noexcept {
        a.swap(b);
    }

    // Other member functions

    void clear() noexcept {
        while (head)
            pop_front();
    }
    bool empty() const noexcept {
        return head == nullptr;
    }
    ListNode* get() const noexcept {
        return head;  // Retain ownership.
    }
    void pop_front() noexcept {
        if (head) {
            auto node{ head };
            head = head->next;
            delete node;
        }
    }
    void push_front(std::vector<int> const& vec) {
        auto it{ vec.crbegin() };
        while (it != vec.crend())
            push_front(*it++);
    }
    void push_front(int const n) {
        head = new ListNode(n, head);
    }
    ListNode* release() noexcept {
        return std::exchange(head, nullptr);  // Relinquish ownership.
    }
    bool operator== (LeetCode_ForwardList const& that) const noexcept {
        auto p{ this->head };
        auto q{ that.head };
        while (p && q)
            if (p->value != q->value)
                return false;
            else
                p = p->next, q = q->next;
        return !p && !q;
    }
    bool operator!= (LeetCode_ForwardList const& that) const noexcept {
        // This function can be omitted in C++20 and later.
        return !(*this == that);
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& ost, LeetCode_ForwardList const& list)
    {
        ost.put('[');
        if (auto node{ list.head }; node)
            for (;;)
            {
                ost << node->value;
                node = node->next;
                if (!node) break;
                ost.put(',');
            }
        ost.put(']');
        return ost;
    }
};
// end file: LeetCode_ForwardList.ixx


@Pepijn Kramer wrote: Leetcode should provide a reference to a std::list [or std::forward_list]. You are, of course, absolutely right. IMO, you are also right about the kick in the pants! Given LeetCode's failing, however, something like this is better than just letting all the nodes leak. On that basis, I commend the OP for recognizing the problem.

@PepijnKramer Indeed, std::list should always replace a custom implementation, leed code might be failing to indicate (didn't peek into) – but if we do implement a custom list (for practicing only) then having a full list class is a good thing, though maybe this answer should add a very first paragraph highlighting the use of standard containers in real code, too.

I have pretty much my doubts over your release function, though. What should one do with these list nodes outside the list? This mainly opens risks for memory leaks. I'd advice against – I wouldn't even expose the list nodes as separate class, instead as a nested one, it's in the end just an implementation detail.

The corresponding counter part is critical as well: List l1; /* fill in some nodes */ List l2(l1.get()); leads to double deletion of at least one node (we might crash after first attempt or whatever else, it is UB).

I added release specifically to interface with the LeetCode Solution class. At that time, I was not sure whether ownership needed to pass to the solution. In the end, I implemented the solution using get, so release could now be deleted. I am curious. Do you feel the same way about std::unique_ptr::release? Should it be deprecated/deleted? Regarding a nested Node class, once again, you are right, except mean-old LeetCode does not give you that option. Its solution interface specifies a ListNode that is not nested.

std::unique_ptr is a different beast: It is designed to hold some data directly. There might be some good reason to get data out without having it deleted. The list nodes do hold data, but they have additional management information (successor and if doubly linked list, predecessor pointers). This is stuff you do not want to expose. The corresponding action to release for the smart pointer would be remove (an element from the list, potentially returning it).

Side note: Removing elements and returning them is not the way std::list handles that. std::list removes elements by destructing them (though in case of raw pointers it is the pointer only that is elimintated, not the object pointed to).

All good points. In the end, this is just a light-weight class intended to patch up some LeetCode failings. It is not intended to be used elsewhere, and it is not intended be industrial-strength library code.

Well, the problem is: LC imposed a fundamental design error on you. Such a get function actually shouldn't ever have been necessary!

I have never seen import and export used before nor have I seen drivers implemented in any of the courses I've seen before in C++ and C. Looks like I'm gonna have to learn how to implement the above because throwing the above code in visual studio gives me errors. I could try to rewrite it in newbie code language, but learning those new tools seems fun. Nothing in my book on them which seems odd. It just list export as a keyword no examples of cases or uses.

The two files are C++ modules, a new form of translation unit that was introduced in C++20. If you open Project Properties, and set "C++ Language Standard" to "Preview - Features from the Latest C++ Working Draft (/std:c++latest)", they will compile in Visual Studio 2022. In file main.cpp, use the declaration import LeetCode_0002_Add_Two_Numbers;, rather than #include, and call function LeetCode_0002_Add_Two_Numbers() to run the program.

Alternatively, you can strip out the keyword export, along with all the import and export declarations, and move the code into .h and .cpp files. The code in file LeetCode_0002_Add_Two_Numbers.ixx should be moved to main.cpp. The code in file LeetCode_ForwardList.ixx should be moved to file LeetCode_ForwardList.h. File main.cpp will then need to include it: #include "LeetCode_ForwardList.h". Afterwards, you will need to figure out which Standard Library header files need to be included in your new files.
